# building a 900Mhz long-range data communications network

Tags: transceiver, ham-radio, digital-communications, digital-modulation

First to be clear: I am a licensed amateur radio operator with about 10 years programming experience and I took electronics in high school (2008). However I tend to stay on the soft side of things. I've forgotten most of what I learned in electronics class (besides what's dangerous and what isn't) but I have been looking into the possibility of building a P2P (backhaul) communications network to deliver messages and communications across long distances. At first I considered bluetooth. The properties of the technology fit almost exactly to what I need. Connection is quick (no waiting like wifi). It has FHSS technology to reduce interference. You can send almost any type of data but the range messed it up for me. Is there an course for building transceivers which doesn't take a million years to finish? Something which doesn't tell every single detail but covers radio circuitry and how it conceptually works? Something involving data transmissions would also be great.

Comment: I'm looking for something I can plug into a USB port and transmit for about 10 miles, point to multipoint but the points need to be instantly interchangeable (for mobiles). I'm looking for a range of around 10 miles with unlicensed access (1 watt transmission). Everything I've found seems to be REALLY expensive or out of my price range.

Comment: Years ago I used some XTend modems that can do those sorts of distances at around 50kbps line of sight with a good directional antenna for about $500. I'd expect developing something similar would need years of learning at least, you're looking at RF design, DSP and data transmission theory. It's in a different leauge to say making a simple FM transmitter / receiver, which isn't insignificant in itself.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you are in north america, so, for a 15km radio link at the 900MHz band, you will need  A modem and antenna that will give you a link budget of ~110dB, this assumes you use the maximum allowed by the FCC (1W). For a USB port that can deliver 0.5W at best, you will need another power source, or limit your transmissions to very short bursts.

You might also need directional antennas (No point to multipoint) and a high (~30m) Tower.
There are modems with such link budget, I have not used them personally.

[A link to the XTend](http://www.digi.com/products/wireless-modems-peripherals/wireless-range-extenders-peripherals/xtend#overview) from the previous poster.

Comment: Actually, I may just make it for HAMs only. They have more privileges at 900 Mhz. The wattage range is raised for them. I looked into XTend but was burdened by the price. I'm more or less looking for something to build to cut costs. Know of any tutorials to build SSB transceivers which explain the physical working concept?

Answer (score 0):

Integrated transceivers and PAs are much easier to use than discrete solution in this frequency. TI, Maxim, Nordic to name few have many options in this band.
However, it will require PCB (design, layout, manufacturing). Either that, or ready made modules from Anaren or similar companies.